# how to connect 2 mongodb databases in springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, multiple-databases

I am currently using 1 mongodb. This is how I set it up in application
spring.data.mongodb.database=Active
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<my_uri>

Now I need to introduce a secondary database named Inactive
How do I set it up in application?
Thank you.

I have tried as below, but it didn't work.
spring.data.mongodb.db1.database=Active
spring.data.mongodb.db1.uri=mongodb+srv://<my_uri>

spring.data.mongodb.db2.database=Inactive
spring.data.mongodb.db2.uri=mongodb+srv://<my_uri>

I keep <my_uri> the same for both Active and Inactive, because I think it is the cluster'uri and both databases are inside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second data source and wire it in to template etc. It is a variant of [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-multiple-databases-spring-data).

```
mongodb.primary.host= mongodb+srv://<my_uri>
mongodb.primary.database=Active
mongodb.primary.authenticationDatabase=admin
mongodb.primary.username=user1
mongodb.primary.password=password
mongodb.primary.port=27017

mongodb.secondary.host= mongodb+srv://<my_uri>
mongodb.secondary.database=Inactive
mongodb.secondary.authenticationDatabase=admin
mongodb.secondary.username=user1
mongodb.secondary.password=password
mongodb.secondary.port=27017
```

Comment: my question is how to set it up in application. mongodb+srv gave me the uri to the whole cluster, which means all databases in the cluster share the same uri. So how i can write the 2nd database in application? Thank you

Comment: I have provided example configuration for your scenario. Further than that you can work out from the link how to only split the DB.